# apache camel 2.9.1 works with spring 3.1.x and Spring 4.x

Tags: spring

Hi Currently I am using camel-2.9.1 with default underlying dependency spring 3.0.5. This is working fine in production. Now I have to use some feature of Spring 3.1.x or Spring 4.x.
Will camel-2.9.1 works if I replace underlying spring jars to 3.1.x or Spring 4.x.
Since it is already in production i don't want to upgrade camel jars.
Will same camel-jars of 2.9.1 works with Spring 3.1.x or spring 4.x